# Container that changes size

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using flutter and I'm trying to create a kind of post card similar to a tweet.

I want to make a card when the text has different numbers of lines or an image is inside the container.

How do I make the container change size depending on what is inside?

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: width,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                  bottom:
                      BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: Color(0xFFF525151)))),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 5, top: 5, right: 5, bottom: 2),
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 25.0,
                          backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                            pictureprofil,
                          ),
                        )
                      ]),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Container(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(username,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 15.5,
                                          fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    pseudo,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 15.5,
                                        fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                                        color: Colors.orange),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                          5,
                          0,
                          0,
                          0,
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          '2h',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 15.5,
                            fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 0, 0, 0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () => _likedChange(),
                                child: Icon(
                                  liked
                                      ? Icons.favorite_border_outlined
                                      : Icons.favorite,
                                  color: liked ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                                  size: 19,
                                )),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
                              child: Text(
                                countlike,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15.5,
                                  fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () => _dislikedChange(),
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.bolt,
                                  color:
                                      disliked ? Colors.white : Colors.red,
                                  size: 18.2,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(countdislike,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 15.5,
                                  fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                                )),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 55.0),
                child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: width / 1.2,
                        height: height / 6,
                        /*decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(color: null, width: 0.5)),*/
                        child: Text(
                          textbulle,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            height: 1.15,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                            fontSize: 15.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(55, 8, 5, 8),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => CommentsPopPage()));
                      },
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => CommentsPopPage()));
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.chat_bubble_outline,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                      child: Text(
                        countcomment,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15.5,
                          fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => EkoPopPage()));
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.adjust,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 20,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                      child: Text(
                        counteko,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15.5,
                          fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.layers_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                      child: Text(
                        countcalque,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 15.5,
                          fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 22),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.share,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 16.5,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      BulleTendance()));
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          themebulle,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            fontSize: 15.5,
                            fontFamily: 'DBIcons',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          showModalBottomSheet(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) {
                                return Column(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: new Icon(Icons.block),
                                      title: new Text('Bloquer'),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: new Icon(Icons.flag),
                                      title: new Text('Signaler'),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: new Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
                                      title: new Text('Statistiques'),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    ListTile(
                                      leading: new Icon(Icons.delete),
                                      title: new Text('Supprimer'),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                );
                              });
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 16.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          showLikeOverLay
              ? Icon(
                  Icons.favorite,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 80,
                )
              : Container(),
          showDislikeOverLay
              ? Icon(
                  Icons.bolt,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 80,
                )
              : Container()
        ])
      ],
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: try Expanded instead of Container

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question